# How can I generate cert.pem and key.pem to deploy in an kubernetes cluster with helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I try to install the DB2 with the command:

```
helm install --name stocktrader-db2 ibm-charts/ibm-db2oltp-dev --tls \
--set db2inst.instname=db2inst1 --set db2inst.password=start1a \
--set options.databaseName=STRADER --set peristence.useDynamicProvisioning=true \
--set dataVolume.size=20Gi --set dataVolume.storageClassName=ibmc-block-gold
```

I get the following error message:

> could not read x509 key pair (cert: "/Users/name/.helm/cert.pem", key:
>   "/Users/name/.helm/key.pem"): can't load key pair from cert
>   /Users/name/.helm/cert.pem and key /Users/name/.helm/key.pem: open
>   /Users/name/.helm/cert.pem: no such file or directory

=> What is the default directory for the files cert.pem and key.pem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are following their `README.md`, the installation instructions there assume you have [Tiller setup in your cluster with TLS enabled](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/tiller_ssl.md).

If you remove the `--tls` flag from the command (`helm install --name stocktrader-db2 ibm-charts/ibm-db2oltp-dev --set db2inst.instname=db2inst1 --set db2inst.password=start1a --set options.databaseName=STRADER --set peristence.useDynamicProvisioning=true --set dataVolume.size=20Gi --set dataVolume.storageClassName=ibmc-block-gold`) it will not attempt to find the certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you need TLS between helm and tiller, follow [this link](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/tiller_ssl.md#generating-certificate-authorities-and-certificates). Also, per [this link](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/tiller_ssl.md#configuring-the-helm-client), copy the certificates into helm's home directory:

```
$ cp ca.cert.pem $(helm home)/ca.pem
$ cp helm.cert.pem $(helm home)/cert.pem
$ cp helm.key.pem $(helm home)/key.pem
```

Then, run the `helm install --name stocktrader-db2 ...` command.

Answer (score 1):

I removed TLS from the following command:

```
helm install --name stocktrader-db2 ibm-charts/ibm-db2oltp-dev
--tls
--set db2inst.instname=db2inst1
--set db2inst.password=ThisIsMyPassword
--set options.databaseName=STRADER
--set peristence.useDynamicProvisioning=true
--set dataVolume.size=20Gi
--set dataVolume.storageClassName=glusterfs
```

If TLS is need the helm configuration can be done via the following installation procedure:

https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#securing-your-helm-installation